# Can't export a polygon shapefile to MySQL using ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr2ogr, fwtools

I am having problems with ogr2ogr and keep getting different versions of the error:

ERROR 1: MySQL error message: The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes. 
Description: ALTER TABLE 'test_poly' ADD SPATIAL INDEX('SHAPE')

my command (entering it in FWTools Shell) is:

ogr2ogr -f "MySQL" MYSQL:"test,host=27.0.0.1,user=root,port=3306" -nln test_poly -a_srs "EPSG:3857"  -update -overwrite

...adding '-lco GEOMETRY_NAME ' doesn't do anything...
...also moving the  ti tge ebdm behind -lco engine=MYSIAM does nothing...

All I see is the tables 'geometry_columns' and spatial_ref_sys' and 'test_poly' being created...but no data *(i.e. when I use "Select Rows - Limit 1000").

What am I missing?

I am a bit new to MySQL...but I read as much documentation as I could find...I thought I could set the spatial index by going to Engine: MYSIAM....am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reference:

`Location` GEOMETRY NOT NULL,

spatial indexes should be created on **GEOMETRY types**.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_poly` (
        `Id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
        `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
        `Location` GEOMETRY NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
        SPATIAL KEY (`Location`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282962/error-creating-spatial-index-on-mysql-blob-column

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue you must add `-lco ENGINE=MyISAM` to your ogr2ogr command.

> -lco NAME=VALUE:
>   Layer creation option (format specific)

[GDAL ogr2ogr docs](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)

In this case this parameter sets storage engine for MySQL table(s). In MySQL 5.6 spatial indexes supports only on this storage engine.

> For indexing spatial columns, MyISAM supports both SPATIAL and non-SPATIAL indexes. The other storage engines support non-SPATIAL indexes, as described in Section 13.1.13, “CREATE INDEX Syntax”.

[Mysql Extensions for Spatial Data docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Something to be aware of is that your one line answer is attracting flags from other users, and risks your answer being deleted.  I recommend "about a paragraph" being considered as minimum length for both questions and answers here.  Would you be able to use the edit button beneath your answer to expand upon it slightly, please?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE. I suggest you give an example command line to expand your answer otherwise you risk having your answer voted for deletion.